# Azure Defender for Cloud reporting issues that have already been fixed

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-aks, azure-policy

I have an AKS cluster where a few security recommendations are reported. I believe I have mitigated some of them already, but they are still shown.

Namely, there is

> - Container images should be deployed from trusted registries only
> - Azure Kubernetes Service clusters should have Defender profile enabled
> - Kubernetes clusters should disable automounting API credentials

[image]

---

Let's look at the last one as that's pretty straightforward. When I click at it for details, then `View policy definition`, I see that it's assigned to the cluster.

[image]

For some reason navigating to the assignment and `View compliance` shows a page with an error (`Please provide below info when asking for support: timestamp xxx`) and no resources. But going to the cluster page, then `Policies > go to Azure Policy`, I can see that the policy is OK and targets one resource (my AKS cluster) so all should be fine.

[image]

Yet, this exact policy that is reporting OK is still listed as problematic in the Defender for Cloud list. Why is that? The same case applies to the other policies as well.